# How can I read the RGB value of a given pixel of an active window?

Tags: python, windows

If I have a coordinate on the screen, is it possible to retrieve the RGB value of it without taking a screenshot first?

I am working with this:

```
import time
from ctypes import *

GetForegroundWindow = windll.user32.GetForegroundWindow
GetWindowDC = windll.user32.GetWindowDC
GetPixel = windll.gdi32.GetPixel
ReleaseDC = windll.user32.ReleaseDC
foreground_window = GetForegroundWindow()
dc = GetWindowDC(foreground_window)
rgb = GetPixel(dc, 10, 0)
ReleaseDC(foreground_window, dc)

r = rgb & 0xff
g = (rgb >> 8) & 0xff
b = (rgb >> 16) & 0xff
print "RGB(%d, %d, %d)" % (r, g, b)
```

I found that here, and I like how it involves `ctypes`.

I have this problem:

How do I `setcursorposition` to the same spot I am sampling the colour from? With this?

`ctypes.windll.user32.SetCursorPos(100, 100)`

Comment: how do you work with `screen`, what library?

Comment: On what operating system?

Comment: There is no short, elegant solution. But here are a few ways:

https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Color_of_a_screen_pixel#Python

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are missing an import. In Windows you do it like this:

```
import win32api
win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
```